# Hide leading stars in helm-org-in-buffer-headings

Tags: org-mode, helm, helm-sources

Currently, when I run `helm-org-in-buffer-headings` in see something like this:

```
* main topic 1
** Subtopic 1.1
** Subtopic 1.2
*** Sub-subtopic 1.2.1
* main topic 2
```

I would like to hide the leading stars and remove the indentation, so that instead, what you see is this:

```
main topic 1
Subtopic 1.1
Subtopic 1.2
Sub-subtopic 1.2.1
main topic 2
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can hide the first N-1 stars by setting `org-hide-leading-stars` to a non-nil value, although it will still keep the headlines indented.

You can also tweak `helm-org-startup-visibility` to remove all stars and headline indentation:

```
(with-eval-after-load "helm-org"
  (defun helm-org-startup-visibility (candidates _source)
    (setq-local indent-tabs-mode t)
    (cl-loop for i in candidates
         collect
             (cons
              (with-helm-buffer
        (org-indent-remove-properties-from-string
         (replace-regexp-in-string "^\\(\\**\\)\\(\\* \\)" "" (car i))))
              (cdr i)))))
```

Comment: Thanks. I use org-indent-mode currently. I am really looking to remove the leadin stars and the indentation.

Comment: I updated the answer. See if that works for you.

Comment: I updated the answer again to make it work with org-indent-mode.